# How to current route name in react-navigation inside navigation.js file?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation, react-navigation

I want to know the current route name but inside the navigation js file, I use the useRoute hook in any component and work well, but I get this error when I use useRoute inside navigation.js

Error: Couldn't find a route object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

navigation.js code example,

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const route = useRoute(); // show error >> Error: Couldn't find a route object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?
  
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

when I remove useRoute, the Error is gone, But I need to use useRoute or any other way to get current route name inside navigation.js file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass the `navigationContainerRef` from the `NavigationContainer` to the `Navigation` comomponent to make the `navigation` object accessible.

Consider the following code snippet.

```js
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from "@react-navigation/native"

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

const App = () => {
    return <NavigationContainer
              ref={navigationRef}>
                 <Navigation navigation={navigationRef} />
            </NavigationContainer>  
}
export default App
```

Then, inside `Navigation`.

```js
export default function Navigation({ navigation }) {

  const route = navigation.current?.getCurrentRoute()
  
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The current route name get then be accessed using `route?.name`.

**Edit:** As jhon antoy correctly pointed out in the comments, this does not update the current route state if we navigate to a different screen. We need to update this ourselves as follows.

```js
export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();

const App = () => {
  const [routeName, setRouteName] = useState();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        setRouteName(navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name)
      }}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeName;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;
        console.log("route", currentRouteName)
        setRouteName(currentRouteName);
      }}
    >
       <Navigation routeName={routeName} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inside `Navigation`.

```js
export function Navigation(props) {

  const route = props.routeName

  console.log(props)

  return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I have made a [snack with some simple navigation buttons](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/navigationref).

Comment: It worked but when I navigate, the name doesn't change

Comment: You are correct, I have forgotten to add this important detail. Let me fix my answer.

Comment: @jhonantoy check my updated answer please.

Comment: Thank's a lot for this wonderful answer, It worked ^_^

Comment: Thank you. been spending hours on this issue. this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly in v6.

In Your Stack, you have to convert the component to child.. in this way:

```
     <RootStack.Screen
        name={NameOfYourRoute}
        children={props => (
          <NameOfYourStack {...props} currentRoute={currentRoute} />
        )}
      />
```